# saving the cropped image - to amazon s3

Tags: angularjs, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am cropping the image . But When I upload it to the amazon , it saves the originalfile.

```
 function _handleFileSelect(evt) {
                $scope.beforeLogoSelect = false;
                $scope.file = evt.currentTarget.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(evt) {
                    $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
                        $scope.myImage = evt.target.result;
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL($scope.file);
            }
```

This way I get the url of the image and assign it to the cropped image tag.

Now How shal i save the cropped file to a file variable so that I can upload to amazon s3? I want the resultant cropped image in $scope.file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the data uri to blob was the solution.

[Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata)

Might be useful for others.